# Nonetype object has no a attribute leave nextcord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

CODE:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('Servers.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8")as f:
        server_id = guild.id
        str_id = str(server_id)
        f.write("\n " + str_id)
    server = client.get_guild("server_id")
    await server.leave()
```

Error:

`await server.leave("server_id") ^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'leave'` 
Can someone help me find solution for this error?

I'm trying to get server ID upon joining. Write it into text file and then leave the server. I don't know how to leave the server. Upon reading documentation I'm completly clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guild object provided already has an attribute for the id.
Using the provided id from the guild object, you can save an API call (or most likely an internal cache lookup).

**Fixed version**

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    #  Depending on your intention you might have meant to append to the existing "Servers.txt". 
    #  If so use "a" instead of "w" when you are opening the file.
    with open('Servers.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8")as f:
        f.write("\n " + str(guild.id))
    await guild.leave()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying a `string` to the `get_guild` function. You should remove the quotes.

Comment: Yes. Instead (“server_id”) i should have write (server_id), but it doesn’t solve my error.

Comment: It should return a valid `server` if the `server_id` is correct. Can you manually copy the server ID and test it that way?

Comment: @HonzaKudláček https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=leave#discord.Client.get_guild , the only way return value can be `None` is the mentioned guild cannot be found with that guild id. Could you `print(server)` right before `server.leave()`?

Answer (score 0):

`get_guild` seems to be the problem, but it is completely unnecessary in this code as you already have the server object in the `guild` variable. Try simply changing `server.leave()` to `guild.leave()`